# Extracting 3-months blocks from a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have to extract 3-months blocks from a pandas dataframe with historical prcies. I see I can do it in a very heavy way (RX is the data object, dataframe):

```
DateTimeI = pd.DatetimeIndex(RX.iloc[:,0]) # Creating the DatetimeIndex
Block_2015_1a = RX.iloc[DateTimeI.year == 2015, :] # Selecting all the records from 2015
DT_1a = pd.DatetimeIndex(Block_2015_1a.iloc[:,0]) # Creating the new DatetimeIndex
Block_2015_1a = Block_2015_1a.iloc[DT_1a.month <= 3, :] # Selecting all the records for the months 1 to 3.
```

This way will not directly work when I'll need months in differetn years. In Matlab (I'm in the transition form Matlab to Python) the same task can be elegantly done as:

```
Block_2015_1a = RX(RX.Date.Year == 2015 & RX.Date.Month <= 3, :);
```

Is there some similar way to do it with pandas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use vectorized [.dt](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#datetimelike-properties) locator which allows you to extract different parts of datetime:

```
RX.loc[(RX.Date.dt.year == 2015) & (RX.Date.dt.month <= 3), :]
```